# Getting Error: StaticInjectorError[InjectionToken DocumentToken] | NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken DocumentToken

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I am upgrading my app from angular 2.1.2 to angular 5.0.0. and getting this error.

> Error: StaticInjectorError[InjectionToken DocumentToken]: \n 
>   StaticInjectorError[InjectionToken DocumentToken]: \n
>   NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken DocumentToken!\n
>   NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken DocumentToken!\n
>   at _NullInjector.get
>   (/Users/temp/Documents/GitHub/sample-app/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:962:19)\n
>   at resolveToken
>   (/Users/temp/Documents/GitHub/sample-app/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1250:24)\n
>   at tryResolveToken
>   (/Users/temp/Documents/GitHub/sample-app/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1192:16)\n
>   at StaticInjector.get
>   (/Users/temp/Documents/GitHub/sample-app/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1063:20)\n
>   at resolveToken
>   (/Users/temp/Documents/GitHub/sample-app/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1250:24)\n
>   at tryResolveToken
>   (/Users/temp/Documents/GitHub/sample-app/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1192:16)\n
>   at StaticInjector.get
>   (/Users/temp/Documents/GitHub/sample-app/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1063:20)\n
>   at resolveNgModuleDep
>   (/Users/temp/Documents/GitHub/sample-app/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:10623:25)\n
>   at _callFactory
>   (/Users/temp/Documents/GitHub/sample-app/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:10693:32)\n
>   at _createProviderInstance$1
>   (/Users/temp/Documents/GitHub/sample-app/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:10637:26)",

This is not a Angular CLI app so I have created a repo on git for minimal reproduction of the issue. Please refer the following [link](https://github.com/amit-kumar27/sample-app)

Refer `README.md` for build and serve the app.

Using  webpack:3.11.0 For build this app.
Not able to understand the issue.

Comment: check this [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20101).

Comment: @fatemefazli https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23737 `Same as issue #20101 , which is closed now, but not able to find the solution.`

Comment: you need to import HttpModule(deprecated) as well as HttpClientModule, because some dependency still relies on HttpModule.

Comment: or ```import {HttpClientModule, HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

then:
imports:[
HttpClientModule]``` .

Comment: @fatemefazli Already tried this one. It doesn't work with my app. And I already tried the solutions for this issue but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that your server `index.js` bundle contains `@angular/core` code. It means that when you run code you have two different functions `InjectionToken` that create two different instances of `DocumentToken`.

Possible fix is to change `externals` option in

**webpack.config.json**

```
export var serverConfig = {
  ...
  externals: includeClientPackages(
    /@angularclass|@angular|angular2-|.....
  ), 
  externals: angularExternals(),

  ...
}
...
export function angularExternals() {
  return function (context, request, callback) {
    if (request.startsWith('@angular/')) {
      return callback(null, {
        root: ['ng', request.replace(/^@angular//, '')],
        commonjs: request,
        commonjs2: request,
        amd: request
      });
    }
    callback();
  };
}
```

After that index.js bundle won't contain duplicate code from `@angular/core` so that angular will be able resolve dependency successfully.

Answer (score -1):

import {HttpClientModule, HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

then:
imports:[
HttpClientModule]

it will work

Comment: this answer did not solve the problem for me, i got the same error message